# jquery used only on codebehind boolean = true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a modal popup div that displays when a textbox is clicked.  However, I only want this functionality if the user has permissions to this feature, otherwise I want to completely ignore all code associated with the textbox being clicked (ie. the user will just type values into the textbox).  How can I set the JQuery code for textbox click, to only happen based on a boolean variable retrieved in the codebehind from the database?

Comment: Only render that js code to the page if they have the permissions

Comment: Do you want click or focus  event for textbox?

Comment: +1 to @Chad - just don't show the element that they would click to open the modal popup. Further, only IE really supports modal browser popups....please consider another approach.

Comment: I still need the textbox if they don't have permissions, I just don't want the functionality that comes with the JQuery code if they don't have permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this probably

```
<script>
       if ("<%= CodeBehindProperty %>" == "true")
       {
             //Attach click events
       }
</script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way, I wouldn't render the `<script/>` tag *at all* if they don't have the permissions.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it went into the if statement, regardless of whether the boolean was true or false

Comment: You could try to switch to a string compare in javascript, see edit.

Comment: @Chad Not rendering the script tags if they won't be used would probably be idea. But I personally think it's a pain to have .js in the codeBehind and write out with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: doesn't seem to be working.  No matter what the boolean returns, it runs the JQuery.  Here's the code

Comment: That's odd, what's getting rendered out by the <%= %> tags in the HTML if you view it's source?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it once you asked me to check the source.  The boolean was resulting to "True" and I was comparing it to "true".  Case sensitivity killed me.  It's working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can warp the script with a literal control, and open/close it if have permissions as:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="MoreScript" EnableViewState="false">
<script>
  functions MoreToDo(){

  }
</script>
</asp:Literal>
```

and on code behind you just set the `MoreScript.Visible` according to your permissions. I select the Literal because you can add it on the header and is not leave any marks, and also you can direct see the javascript code on page.

Comment: thanks for the idea.  Seemed logical, however it's crashing now with the following error  "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' does not allow child controls.". due to this line in the JQuery,  $('#<%=txtLANG.ClientID %>').click(function(){"

Comment: @MarkHighfield Try then the asp:PlaceHolder, if this not work ether try direct to open/close it with some code like `<% if(show){ %><script>...</script><%}%>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to register the jQuery function from codebehind by useing RegisterStartupScript method.

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String scriptString = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function($){
       $('#Element').click(function(){
       //open popup
       });
    }
    </script>";
    if(hasPermission())
        this.RegisterStartupScript("PopUpScript", scriptString);
 }
```

Comment: not sure why, but I tried this and nothing happened.  It loaded fine, but the JQuery didn't trigger